# Call function or property in another QML File inside a TabView in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, tabview

I want to call `myFunc()` in `PageA.qml` from the `main.qml` (see the `onClicked` event of the `Button`). I tried some property alias stuff, but nothing has worked so far. Any ideas?

Here is my `PageA.qml` code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    function myFunc() { /* ... */ }
    TextField { id: myText }
}
```

And here is my `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    TabView {
        Tab {
            title: "Tab A"
            PageA { }
        }
        // ...
    }
    Button {
        text: "click"
        onClicked: callMyFunc()
    }

    function callMyFunc() {
        // Call myFunc() in PageA.qml or read property "text" of the TextField
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem to call a function in `PageA` stems from the fact that `Tab` does not inherit from `Item`, but from `Loader` hence a direct function call like `tabID.function()` is not possible. You need the `item` property of `Tab`:

```
TabView {
    Tab {
        id: tabA // Give the tab an id
        title: "Tab A"
        PageA { }
    }
    // ...
}
Button {
    text: "click"
    onClicked: callMyFunc()
}

function callMyFunc() {
    tabA.item.myFunc() // Call the function myFunc() in PageA
}
```

Alternatively you can create an alias:

```
TabView {
    id: mytabview
    property alias tabItem : tabA.item
    Tab {
        id: tabA // Give the tab an id
        title: "Tab A"
        PageA { }
    }
    // ...
}
Button {
    text: "click"
    onClicked: callMyFunc()
}

function callMyFunc() {
    mytabview.tabItem.myFunc() // Call the function myFunc() in PageA
}
```

But alias or not alias is more or less a cosmetic choice.

Comment: Thanksss! I forgot the .item while calling the function.